# return the next lowest value

Tags: excel, formula, excel-2013

MS EXCEL 2013:

I am trying to build a formula that will compare a 'reportDate'(DD/MM/YYYY) against other dates in that field return the next highest date. I am going to use this in a *VLOOKUP* / *SUMIFS* to bring back a value from time that the last report was issued.

So here is a summary of my data set.
NOTE: there are multiple [ID]'s in my data set.

```
[ID];[reportDate];[priority]
1;01/11/2014;50
1;01/12/2014;50
1;01/01/2015;45
1;01/02/2015;40
```

I feel like `=LARGE([reportDate],2)` is getting me some of the way there, in that it gives me the correct date for last report. But I don't think this is quite the answer as it only works if there are two rows for each ID.

But here is what what I have so far.

```
=SUMIFS([priority],[ID],[@ID],[reportDate],LARGE([reportDate],2))
```

Thanks you for taking the time to help.

Dan

Comment: Good question, I had not considered that. For the 'value' in this example I am talking about the date. If there is a new ID added thus having no previous data I would probably set the new field output to a blank.

Comment: Apologies, the 'reportDate' is the value that I am trying to compare. As I stated in my OP this data set will contain a snapshot of the status of multiple ID's. Each will have the report date against them, until the ID is closed off. And then will no longer appear in the reports (or my data set). I have ID as my primary key, and 'reportDate' is a dimension. So in short I need to pick out the next highest 'reportDate' from my data set and use this alongside my 'ID' in something like a SUMIFS so that I can calculate the last reported 'priority'. I hope this is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a way of doing this.

I don't think its the best way but it works!

**SUMMARY**

In summary I have created a list of all distinct [reportDate] values, then used this to give me the next oldest date, that will be my [lastReportDate]. This [lastReportDate] along with the [ID] is then used in a SUMIFS formula to retrieve the last reports priority.

**DETAIL**

I have created an auto-refreshing pivot table of only the [reportDate] (so a distinct list).

This has a newest to oldest sort on it. Next to the chart I have an IF statement that checks the cell below and to the left of it and processes a "N/A" if blank. That is used to tell me where the end of the distinct reportDate table is.

Example (starting at cell A1, sheet called 'DATE distinct')

```
[reportDate];[formula]
01/01/2014;=IF(A3>1,A3,"N/A")
05/02/2014;=IF(A4>1,A4,"N/A")
02/03/2014;=IF(A5>1,A5,"N/A")
02/04/2014;=IF(A6>1,A6,"N/A")
```

I then added the SUMIFS to a new column in my original table to output the last reports priority.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([@[reportDate]],'DATE distinct'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)="N/A","",SUMIFS([priority],[ID],[@ID],[reportDate],VLOOKUP([@[reportDate]],'DATE distinct'!$A:$B,FALSE)))
```

*please note that 'DATE distinct' is the name of the sheet that I stored my distinct dates on.*

Example table with where the above formula is placed.

```
[ID];[reportDate];[priority];[lastReportPriority]
1;01/01/2014;50;{above formula}
1;05/02/2014;50;{above formula}
1;02/03/2015;45;{above formula}
1;02/04/2015;40;{above formula}
14;01/01/2014;20;{above formula}
14;05/02/2014;20;{above formula}
14;02/03/2015;25;{above formula}
20;05/02/2014;20;{above formula}
20;02/03/2015;30;{above formula}
20;02/04/2015;60;{above formula}
```

so the formula will calculate like this...

```
[ID];[reportDate];[priority];[lastReportPriority]
1;01/01/2014;50;
1;05/02/2014;50;50
1;02/03/2015;45;50
1;02/04/2015;40;45
14;01/01/2014;20;
14;05/02/2014;20;20
14;02/03/2015;25;220
20;05/02/2014;20;
20;02/03/2015;30;20
20;02/04/2015;60;30
```